# need to get index of sub array of array by typescript?

Tags: arrays, typescript, sub-array

I have an array like

```
let reportData = [
    {
        ReportID: 1,
        ReportHead: 'Revenue',
        collection: 75,
        subtasks: [
            {
                ReportID: 2, ReportHead: 'Plan timeline', collection: 100, isDeleted: false,
            },
            {
                ReportID: 3, ReportHead: 'Plan budget', collection: 100, isDeleted: false,
            },
            {
                ReportID: 4, ReportHead: 'Allocate resources', collection: 100, isDeleted: false,
            },
            {
                ReportID: 5, ReportHead: 'Income complete', collection: 0, isDeleted: false,
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        ReportID: 6,
        ReportHead: 'Liabilities',
        subtasks: [
            {
                ReportID: 7, ReportHead: 'Software Specification', collection: 60, isDeleted: false,
            },
            {
                ReportID: 8, ReportHead: 'Develop prototype', collection: 100, isDeleted: false,
            },
            {
                ReportID: 9, ReportHead: 'Get approval from customer', collection: 100, isDeleted: false,
            },
        ]
    }
]
```

I need to get index and sub array index from this array. like a data 'ReportID: 7' this array index is 1 and the sub array index is 0 by typescript

Comment: And the problem is?

Comment: I need to get index and sub array index from this array

Comment: That's still not a problem but a requirement. A problem would require actual code that doesn't work -> [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [mcve], and maybe [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try smth like this:

```
const result = reportData.reduce((acc, el, idx) => {
  el.subtasks.forEach((innerEl, innerIdx) => {
    acc[innerEl.ReportID] = { arrayIdx: idx, subArrayIdx: innerIdx }
  });

  return acc;
}, {});
```

Result:

```
{
  '2': { arrayIdx: 0, subArrayIdx: 0 },
  '3': { arrayIdx: 0, subArrayIdx: 1 },
  '4': { arrayIdx: 0, subArrayIdx: 2 },
  '5': { arrayIdx: 0, subArrayIdx: 3 },
  '7': { arrayIdx: 1, subArrayIdx: 0 },
  '8': { arrayIdx: 1, subArrayIdx: 1 },
  '9': { arrayIdx: 1, subArrayIdx: 2 }
}
```

Comment: can I get an index for a particular one. like 'ReportID: 7' and get arrayIdx: 1, subArrayIdx:0

Comment: @AbdusSalam
```
const searchReport = reportId => {
  for (let i = 0; i < reportData.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < reportData[i].subtasks.length; j++) {
      if (reportData[i].subtasks[j].ReportID === reportId) {
        return { arrayIdx: i, subArrayIdx: j }
      }
    }
  }
};

searchReport(7)
```
Result: { arrayIdx: 1, subArrayIdx: 0 }

Comment: dear nice to meet your ans. Now how can I remove or update this row?

Comment: const result = reportData.reduce((acc, el, idx) => {
      el.subtasks.forEach((innerEl, innerIdx) => {
        if (innerEl.ReportID != 7) {
          acc[innerEl.ReportID] = { arrayIdx: idx, elIdx: innerIdx }
        }
      });
      return acc;
    }, {}); I do this but How can I get the reportData?